# Set the height of the div

Tags: html, css, height

I want to set the height of the section based upon the child elements but unfortunately I don't know what's wrong with my code. When I try to decrease the size of the screen the content in the paragraph and the img is overflowing.

**HTML**

```
<div id="section2" class="about">
      <div class="container-section">
         <div class="about-content col-lg-6">
            <p></p>
         </div>
         <div class="about-pic col-lg-2">
            <img />
         </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.about{
height: auto;
margin: 0;
}
.about .container-section{
padding: 0;
height: auto;
position: relative;
}
.about .container-section .about-content p{
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
text-align: justify;
}
.about .container-section .about-pic img{
height: auto;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to see the CSS/Javascript code you're using to attempt to adjust the DIV height...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you're using Bootstrap, right? And Bootstrap is adding some floats, which removes elements from the page flow, and thus the container behaves as if those elements aren't in it. Try adding a cleared div in various places and see if it solves your issue, like so:

```
<div id="section2" class="about">
  <div class="container-section">
     <div class="about-content col-lg-6">
        <p></p>
     </div>
     <div class="about-pic col-lg-2">
        <img />
     </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it adds extra free space, I wanna set the height according to the content...thanks anyway...

Comment: You could always add a clear to other elements, or add a height:.001em; to the clear div...

Comment: Is the page up somewhere where I could take a look, or could you whip up a fiddle for it?